# Software Updates: How do I restart later (to install) rather than now?

Tags: updates, 22.04, reboot

My PC is setup to autostart a number of programs (Scrivener in Wine, OpenOffice, Firefox) so I can turn my computer on in the morning, go make a cup of tea and come back ten minutes later with everything ready to go.

With Ubuntu 20.04, when doing software updates, I had the option to "Restart Later".

Ubuntu 22.04 only gives me the option to "Update & Restart" which is pain in the proverbial because I have to come back to my PC ten minutes after I've done that to turn it off again.

How do I install the updates now and restart later?

Thanks.

Comment: What command are you using or what do you select to get the update and restart prompt. I have never seen that option.

Comment: It's the "Software" program built into Ubuntu.  The icon is a white suitcase with a red-orange-square, a purple circle and a blue-green triangle in it. The "Software Updates" program works as I want it to.  Should i just disable Software, is that possible?

Comment: Okay, so I think what I'll do is let Software nag me through the Taskbar, but do updates on the command line.